# Joining relevant items after splitting list

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a script that parses text from a text-file into a CSV file to achieve this I am using the CSV library.

As far as background goes for this task, I have roughly one hundred switches which I need to pull the *serial number* & *PIDVID* off; I am running that command on the Cisco switches via a script I've written then all of the output is being written to a text-file *(See below for an example of what the text-file might look like)*

```
switch# show inventory 
NAME: "Chassis", DESCR: "Nexus5020 Chassis"
PID: N5K-C5020P-BF     , VID: V04 , SN: SSI13390FZT
```

As you can see from the text-file above it's quite well laid out already the problem ensues when I am trying to write this to a CSV file. When I write this to a CSV file I face the issue that each item is placed in a separate column however, I need the relevant items to appear in the same column, below is my current solution of achieving that.

```
with open(inputFile) as IFR:
    inputFileLines = list(IFR)

    bannedStrings = ['switch# show inventory', 'NAME:']
    bannedString = ''.join(bannedStrings)

    for inputFileLines in inputFileLines:
        if bannedString in inputFileLines:
            inputFileLines.remove(bannedString)
    print(inputFileLines)


listSplit = inputFileLines.split()

listItemA = listSplit[0] + listSplit[1] + listSplit[2] + listSplit[3] + 
listSplit[4]
listItemC = listSplit[5] + listSplit[6] + listSplit[7]

liA = listItemA.replace(',', ' ')
liC = listItemC.replace(',', ' ')

CFR = csv.writer(open('Output.csv', 'a'))
CFR.writerow([liA, liC])
```

By looking at the code you can see this is *incredibly* inefficient method, due to the fact that this would require each text-file I input to look the same, have every single list item in the same place and could not have more list items as I've not accounted for those when concatenating the relevant items based on their current positions in the split list.

Here is an example of what the CSV file looks like after running a text-file through my script.

[image]

---

My challenge - *what is a better way of making sure relevant items from a split list are displayed in the same column?*

Comment: Could you provide some of the text you are operating on?

Comment: Pretty sure that `csv.writerow` escapes commas for you, so you don't have to.

Comment: Are you sure? When I was using it I did notice that there were still commas in-front of list items (Hence why I did it manually) however I can try again... `csvwriter.writerow(row)
Write the row parameter to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current dialect.` - No mention of that

Comment: I think you need a more complex lexer/parser for your input file.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa Do you perhaps have any recommendations for that?

Comment: I do not know the full structure of your file, but apparently there is a pattern that you have uppercase keys with a colon, a whitespace, a value and a comma. You could use the `re` to define a regex to parse your files, or split your lines at `','` and split them again at `':'` to extract the keys and values. In addition you have lines with only one string (like `switch`) prepending sections? I do not know enough about the whole structure of the file to give a definitive answer. Please provide more lines of your file, so that we can see the whole structure.

Comment: Apologies if I am being dim - when you say "file" do you mean my text file? If so, that is the text file. Starting from "switch#" downwards that is the text file, that is all that is in it. It's an output from running a "show inventory" command on a Cisco switch. If you mean code, sure thing.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa As per your last comment, I couldn't tell if you were talking about more text-file content (see comments on that above) or code, subsequently I have added the entire function for what I am achieving in regards to parsing this with CSV.

Comment: I see that it depends on the dialect that you are using whether it will quote the delimiter or not.

Comment: Please also add your expected output for the example you have given. Could you give an example showing multiple entries? Or do you have multiple files with just one entry?

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) to read in your text file. This will give you a list of values for each row split based on where the commas are.

Each switch entry appears to only contain two rows of information so these could be read in based on the number of elements found in each row as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['NAME', 'DESCR', 'PID', 'VID', 'SN'])

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) == 2:
            row1 = [v.split(':')[1].replace('"', '').strip() for v in row] 
        elif len(row) == 3:
            row2 = [v.split(':')[1].replace('"', '').strip() for v in row] 
            csv_output.writerow(row1 + row2)
```

Giving you `output.csv` containing:

```
NAME,DESCR,PID,VID,SN
Chassis,Nexus5020 Chassis,N5K-C5020P-BF,V04,SSI13390FZT
Chassis,Nexus5020 Chassis,N5K-C5020P-BF,V04,SSI13390FZT
Chassis,Nexus5020 Chassis,N5K-C5020P-BF,V04,SSI13390FZT
```

My output assumes that your file contains multiple similar entries. If chassis information is not needed:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['PID', 'VID', 'SN'])

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) == 3:
            csv_output.writerow(v.split(':')[1].replace('"', '').strip() for v in row)
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that in my implementation I explicitly remove the Chassis information - this could work though, thank you! I will need to try this. It's at least a lot more efficient than my current implementation. Thank you, I will revert back upon testing

Comment: That would make it simpler, I have added a 2nd version.